Как вывести значение из PHP в JavaScript через row.$st в DataTables?
Как вывести значение из PHP в JS через row.$st
У меня получается пингует коммутатор и выводит значение 0 или 1. типа онлайн или офлайн
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var table = jQuery('#developers').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/se/nk/ic.php",
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "aoColumns": [
      {
        mData: 'id'
      },
      {
        mData: 'seg'
      },
      {
        mData: 'col'
      },
      {
        mData: 'adres'
      },
      {
        mData: 'dom'
      },
      {
        mData: 'pod'
      },
      {
        targets: [1],
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return '<a id="pod" href="/se/nk/ip/sw.php?ip=' + row.ipi + '">' + row.$st + '</a>';
        }
      },
      {
        mData: 'mac'
      },
      {
        mData: 'sn'
      },
      {
        mData: 'comm'
      },
      {
        mData: 'patch'
      }
    ]
  });
});


вот второй код, откуда он берет данные. и мне надо, чтобы он брал значение $st и показывал на таблице. или же другой код написать, чтобы выводило в таблице онлайн или офлайн. Никак не могу вывести значение $st вместо $ что-то другое надо же?
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');?>
<?php
include_once("co.php");
$sql_query = "SELECT id, seg, col, adres, dom, pod, tar, ipi, mac, sn, comm, patch, dpatch, ont, dont, com FROM nk";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
$developers_record = array();
while( $developer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
    $developers_record[] = $developer;
}
$developer_data = array(
    "sEcho" => 1,
"iTotalRecords" => count($developers_record),
"iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($developers_record),
  "aaData"=>$developers_record);

echo json_encode($developer_data);



$ip ='ipi';
$iplist = array
( array ("$ip") );

$i = count ($iplist);
$results = [];
for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
    $ip = $iplist[$j] [0];
    $ping = exec ("ping -n 1 $ip", $output,$st);
    $results[] = $st;
}

exit;
?>


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
